# How to use datapump in SQLDEVELOPER EC2 WINDOWS

Tags: oracle, migration, amazon-rds, datapump

I am in the process of migrating from Oracle 11g on premise to AWS RDS ORACLE 19C.  to connect to my target database, I installed SQL DEVELOPER on an EC2 Windows Server instance.  I am running the following script and I have an error.  help me please

```
 Error
```

ORA-39001: invalid argument value
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS SYS ERROR,
line 79
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMSDATAPUMPP",
line 4929
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS DATAPUMP".
, line 6880

Comment: My scriptt : DECLARE
v hdnl NUMBER;
BEGIN
v hdnl := DBMS DATAPUMP.OPEN (operation=> 'IMPORT',
DBMS DATAPUMP.ADD FILE ( handle => v hdnl, filename => 'exp_full_gesxxxx.dmp", directory => DATA PUMP DIR',
, job mode =>'SCHEMA',job name =>null, version =>"COMPIATIBLE');
filetype => dbms_datapump.kus_file_type_dump_file);
DBMS DATAPUMP.ADD FILE( handle => v_hdnl, filename => 'expdp_0304.log', directory => 'DATA_PUMP_DIR',
filetype => dbms_datapump.ku$_file_type_log_file);
DBMS DATAPUMP.METADATA FILTER (v hdnl, 'SCHEMA EXPR','IN ("ANONYMOUS")'');
DBMS DATAPUMP.START_JOB (v_hdnl);
END;

Comment: Please edit your original question to include your script, rather than placing it in the comments. Make sure you have proper formatting so that we can read it easily.